# Pagination with WP_Query is buggy - working for some pages, but not the others

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

I'm having a very peculiar bug with pagination :( I'm trying to display 4 posts per page for a category with slug "lastest-news".

The pagination function seems to work correctly. There are 33 posts. The pagination gets constructed correctly with 9 pages and links of following format: /category/lastest-news/page//

The interesting thing is that it works correctly (displaying 4 posts per page) from page 1-4 including. However, for pages 5-9 it doesn't work at all. It doesn't even seem to serve the template... the only error that I could spot is  of the page saying "Nothing found for  Category Lastest-news Page 5".

I would understand if it won't work at all, but for randomly 4 pages and not more?

I would really really appreciate any help! I've spend about over 4 hours trying to figure out what's wrong and it's bugging me.

Thanks for help :)

I'm using the following code for query:

```
<?php 
$page = get_query_var('paged');
$posts_on_page = new WP_Query("posts_per_page=4&category_name=lastest-news&paged=".$page);

//loop to display every one of 4 posts

//pagination
pagination($posts_on_page->max_num_pages);
?>
```

I'm using pagination function from this post: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin

Here is the function (which seems to work fine):

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 2){  
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class='pagination'>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress does its own query on every page. You should modify that query instead of creating a new one. What happens now is that WordPress does a query with the standard posts per page of 10, but you don't do anything with these results and do your own query. This works... until WordPress goes beyond post #33, which is on page number 4.

1. WordPress queries 1-10, your template queries 1-4
2. WordPress queries 11-20, your template queries 5-8
3. WordPress queries 21-30, your template queries 9-12
4. WordPress queries 31-40, your template queries 13-16
5. WordPress queries 41-50, but gets no results, so it gives 404. Your template doesn't load.

So instead you should modify the standard query that WordPress will execute, by placing this in your `functions.php` or in a plugin:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse7687_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse7687_pre_get_posts( &$wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->is_category && 'latest-news' == $wp_query->get_queried_object()->slug ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 4 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I thought if I specify my own query everything will be tired up to that... I've added the code to the functions.php but it still seems to have 10 posts per page :S

Comment: I've changed the syntax of the if statement a bit - I think that was the reason. Thank you sooo much for taking time and explaining to me what was wrong :)

Comment: @DashaLuna: Of course, silly me, you can't ask for the current query object before you execute the query!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Jan Fabry reply I've change the syntax a bit. It works well. Thanks Jan for the explanation!!!

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse7687_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse7687_pre_get_posts( &$wp_query ) {
  if ($wp_query->query_vars['category_name'] == 'latest-news'){
    $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 4;
  }
}
```