# Showing one post from each category, paged?

Tags: categories, query-posts, pagination

I want to display one post from each category per page. So the first page would contain the first post of cat A, the first post of cat B and the first post of cat C. The second page would contain the second post of cat A, the second post of cat B and the second post of cat C.

I currently use the following code, but it does not work, I always get the same posts.

```
$category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

foreach($category_ids as $kk=> $cat_id) {
    $cat_name= query_posts( 'cat='.$cat_id.'&posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=ASC&paged='.$paged);
    foreach($cat_name as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
        if (have_posts ()) :
            while (have_posts ()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
                    }
                    else {
                        ?>
                        <?php if( get_the_category_list() ) { ?><p class="alignleft"><span><?php the_category( ', ' ) ?></span></p><?php } ?>
            endwhile;
        endif;
```

Comment: @rajeshrt - What does _"I am facing pro in category..."_ mean?

Comment: i mean "i am not getting right solution using the above code"

Comment: @rajeshrt: Could you edit your question to add a description of what you are trying to do here? I don't get it by reading your code. Maybe include an example of how the result should look? (When you are done, add a new comment and use `@Jan` in it, so I get a notification.)

Comment: @jan  yaa  i want to say that i want the latest post per category that will display on home page and the remaining will be displayed on page/2,page/3 ect. i know their is plugin available but i dont want to use that i want the specific code that will give me that result.

Comment: @rajeshrt: What is the name of that plugin? You can look at the code and learn from it to build your own solution. You must keep in mind the built-in paging system, [otherwise WordPress won't load your template](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7687/pagination-with-wp-query-is-buggy-working-for-some-pages-but-not-the-others/7723#7723).

Comment: the site of the plugin is    http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/latest-post-from-each-category-plugin-for-wordpress/ please suggest something

Comment: @rajeshrt: How should this work with posts that are in multiple categories? What when you are on page 10, but only some categories have 10 items and others have only 5? (And remember to use `@Jan` if you want me to see your reply)

Comment: @rajreshrt: I edited your question, I hope this is what you intended? Also, the code sample seems to miss some code (there is a loose `} else {` in the loop?), can you add that?

Comment: @rajeshrt - It helps if you edit your question instead of clarifying in the comments. That way others who read your question will understand it and not everyone will take the extra effort to read the comments, especially not the hidden ones.

Comment: @rajeshrt: I'm happy to hear you solved your problem. It would be even better [if you posted an answer yourself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77527/i-solved-my-problem-myself-what-do-i-do-with-my-question), so others with the same problem can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only showing one post of each category then in your `query_posts()`

change the

```
&paged='.$paged
```

to

```
&offset='.$paged
```